# Qt: Configure menu item doesn't appear on Tools menu on mac

Tags: macos, qt, menu

On OS X, if I add a menu item named 'Configure' to my 'Tools' menu, it doesn't appear when the program is run. If I change the name by one character, it appears when run.

On Windows, the menu item always appear. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: I edited the wording a bit to be more clear, as I understood it. If I got it wrong, please edit to fix!

Comment: Actually, re-reading the title, I probably got it wrong (did rollback), you mean the configure entry. But then it makes no sense. How can you observe it "disappearing", when you just add it? It shows for a second and then no longer, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS X, menu items may automatically be moved into the applications menu based on their text. Quit, About and Preferences will be moved if their menu role is QAction::TextHeuristicRole. If the role is changed to QAction::NoRole they won't be moved.

It appears that menu items that are popout menus fail to be moved. They are deleted from the original menu and not added to the application menu.